# How to stop a running .bat file which runs after every 10 minutes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, perl

I have written a .bat file which runs every 10 minute. The problem is now when i want to stop it it never stops. (This .bat file further calls a perl file in the code).

What can be done to kill it ? I tried to turn off PC but it still runs after every 10 mins and disturbs me every 10 mins.

I am not able to find it in task manager by it's name(which is final.bat and neither the perl file which the batch code calls every 1 minute on launchign again and again) http://prntscr.com/5sc7cq

My .bat code for file final.bat is:

```
###################################
schtasks /tr C:\Path\final.bat /sc minute /mo 10 
perl C:\Path\w3.pl
##########################################
```

How to permanently kill this batch running batch file which invokes every 10 minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the task scheduler and remove all tasks you have seem to have scheduled over and over again.

```
start -> run -> taskschd.msc
```

Comment: thanks for answer. You mean in terminal i have to taskschd.msc ?

Comment: If you mean by terminal, the command prompt then yes. I'm curious how many tasks you have scheduled by now as it doubles every 10 minutes.

Comment: How many tasks you had to kill?

Comment: You can also use `schtasks` itself to control the scheduling: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for all the different calls.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers just 1 .. but it do not double every minute.. i am sorry i cudnt understand very well this line "it doubles every 10 minute"

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i deleted the task now it dont run every minute even if i relaunch it. it is just launching on double click it but it do not repeat after 10 minutes

Comment: the batch script do not execute after 10 minute i am getting this when i open task scheduler http://prntscr.com/5snjkk (I ahve it in taskscheduler but it do not launch the .bat )

Comment: My assumption was that if you run the batch file that schedules the task every 10 minutes, it would schedule a new one to every 10 minutes. My assumption was wrong <g>.